# Unable to perform Action class operations on GeckoDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

Unable to perform right click operation in below link.
Have tried almost all the cases to automate it.
https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/context_menu

I am using Selenium 3.3 and geckodrivers latest version.

Actions act = new Actions(driver);  act.moveToElement(element).click(); act.contextClick(element).build().perform(); act.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).bu‌​ild().perform();

Answer (score 0):

Selenium 3 has issues with Actions Class so Can you please try the same code with 2.53.1 version.

Comment: I tried with 2.53.1 version as well, can it be related to browser version ? this is my code Actions act = new Actions(driver); 
  
  act.moveToElement(element).click();  
  
  
  act.contextClick(element).build().perform();
  act.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).build().perform();

Comment: it is working on chrome with 2.53 and 3.3.0 but not on firefox using geckodriver.